# Read XML file using VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I require some direction with where to look with reading XML files

I have been tasked with taking the below XML file (shorten version for this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<CompositeDoors>
    <CompositeDoor  
        AddOnLeft1="[] Eurocell door 15mm" 
        AddOnLeft1_Code="b95e1973f58e747b3e4f7d251097fe9d">
        <Door 
            CylinderType="[ZL30-30NAS] base Standard Satin Chrome Cylinder [Nickel]" 
            CylinderType_Code="112b68d790bc50a835e1c1b1589e57a0" 
        />
    </CompositeDoor>
    <Sidelights>
        <Sidelight 
            Coupler="Eurocell window Coupler" 
            Coupler_Code="03f7f14d5d3484f61fab9fd15239a3e0" 
        />
        <Sidelight
            ArgonGas="Argon Gas" 
            ArgonGas_Code="No" 
            Coupler="Eurocell window Coupler" 
            Coupler_Code="03f7f14d5d3484f61fab9fd15239a3e0" 
        />
    </Sidelights>
    <Topbox 
        ArgonGas="Argon Gas" 
        ArgonGas_Code="No" 
        Glazed="Yes" 
        TopboxDrop="380" 
    />
</CompositeDoors>
```

and to convert it into a xml file another program can read (something like this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<order>
<Header>
    <customer_code>3080</customer_code>
    <del._Name></del._Name>
    <Del._Address_1>Unit 1, </Del._Address_1>
</Header>
<Frame_1>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Overall_Width>950</Overall_Width>
    <Overall_Height>2050</Overall_Height>
</Frame_1>
<Frame_2>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Overall_Width>950</Overall_Width>
    <Overall_Height>2050</Overall_Height>   
</Frame_2>
<Frame_3>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Overall_Width>950</Overall_Width>
    <Overall_Height>2050</Overall_Height>
</Frame_3>
<Frame_4>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Overall_Width>950</Overall_Width>
    <Overall_Height>2050</Overall_Height>
</Frame_4>

</order>
```

I'm trying to use this code to cycle through the nodes to find the relevant parts but I'm struggling

```
While reader.Read()
    ' Check for start elements. '
    If reader.IsStartElement() Then
        If reader.Name = "CompositeDoors" Then
        ElseIf reader.Name = "CompositeDoor" Then
            lbHD_customer_code.InnerText = reader("CustomerAccountCode")
        ElseIf reader.Name = "Sidelight" Then
        For Each m_node In m_nodelist
            framenumber = framenumber + 1
            If framenumber = 1 Then
```

if any one can help that would be fantastic, but even a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Reading the nodes, writing them to the other file or what exactly?

Comment: reading the second sidelight node attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the full code as its around 300 lines but this is how i achieved my solution 
each node is checked against an array to see if i need to use it it then allocates a frame against each section

looping through the xml feels like it is going round the houses but it gives me my result

```
  Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
    m_xmld = New XmlDocument
    Dim framenumber As Int16 = 0
    Dim tags() As String = {"CompositeDoor", "Door", "Sidelight", "Topbox"}
    Dim txt As String = ""
    ' Create an XML reader.
    Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(File)
        m_xmld.Load(File)
        m_nodelist = m_xmld.GetElementsByTagName("Sidelight")
        While reader.Read()
            ' Check for start elements.

            If reader.IsStartElement() Then
                ' See if perls element or article element.
                '  MsgBox(reader.Name)

                If tags.Contains(reader.Name) Then

                    If reader.Name = "Topbox" Then
                        framenumber = 4
                    End If

                    If framenumber = 0 Then

                        Header.Visible = True
                        ' Header Info
                        lbHD_customer_code.InnerText = reader("CustomerAccountCode")
                        lbHD_del_Name.InnerText = reader("Delivery_Reference")
                        lbHD_Del_Address_1.InnerText = reader("Delivery_Address1")
                        lbHD_Del_Address_2.InnerText = reader("Delivery_Address2")
                        lbHD_Del_Address_3.InnerText = reader("Delivery_County")
 End If
            End If
        End While
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW!  Hard to see the relationship between the two.  Here is a piece of code that might  get you started.  The snippet contains two links you should read.

```
'
'read about 
'XElement Class
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.8
'Xml literals
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xml-literals/xml-element-literal
'
Dim inxe As XElement
'to load from file
' inxe = XElement.Load("path to file")
'for testing
inxe = <CompositeDoors>
           <CompositeDoor
               AddOnLeft1="[] Eurocell door 15mm"
               AddOnLeft1_Code="b95e1973f58e747b3e4f7d251097fe9d">
               <Door
                   CylinderType="[ZL30-30NAS] base Standard Satin Chrome Cylinder [Nickel]"
                   CylinderType_Code="112b68d790bc50a835e1c1b1589e57a0"
               />
           </CompositeDoor>
           <Sidelights>
               <Sidelight
                   Coupler="Eurocell window Coupler"
                   Coupler_Code="03f7f14d5d3484f61fab9fd15239a3e0"
               />
               <Sidelight
                   ArgonGas="Argon Gas"
                   ArgonGas_Code="No"
                   Coupler="Eurocell window Coupler"
                   Coupler_Code="FOOOOOOOOO03f7f14d5d3484f61fab9fd15239a3e0"
               />
           </Sidelights>
           <Topbox
               ArgonGas="Argon Gas"
               ArgonGas_Code="No"
               Glazed="Yes"
               TopboxDrop="380"
           />
       </CompositeDoors>

Stop 'step through the code
Dim framePROTO As XElement = <Frame id=""></Frame>
Dim frameID As Integer = 1
Dim outxe As XElement = <order></order>
For Each el As XElement In inxe...<Sidelight>
    Dim newFrame As New XElement(framePROTO)
    newFrame.@id = frameID.ToString
    frameID += 1
    Dim itm As XElement = <itm><%= el.@Coupler %></itm>
    itm.@code = el.@Coupler_Code
    newFrame.Add(itm)
    outxe.Add(newFrame)
Next
Stop '  examine outxe
```

Comment: thank you for your help, it helped me with my knowledge of xml and helped me achieve my final solution